# Pandas - Find unique values that show in every class group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a python pandas table as follows:

```
class  |     id
_____________________
  A      12311894945
  A      12311760566
  A      12311433981
  A      12299990440       
  A      12291758744
  B      12311894945
  B      12311760566
  B      12311433981
  B      12299990440       
  B      12291758744
  C      12299990440       
  C      12291758744
```

I want to get the unique id values such that belong to every class group so that the expected result is as follows:

```
[12299990440, 12291758744]
```

I was thinking maybe a groupby class and some kind of intersection but I couldn't see how those two operations are done together in Pandas.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
uniques = df.groupby('id')['class'].nunique()

uniques[uniques.eq(df['class'].nunique()) ].index
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([12291758744, 12299990440], dtype='int64', name='id')
```

Answer (score 4):

Using set intersection and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

unique_by_group = df.groupby("class")["id"].apply(set)
reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, unique_by_group)

>>> {12291758744, 12299990440}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another alternative with pivotting:

```
s = pd.crosstab(df['id'],df['class']).astype(bool).all(1)
#s = df.pivot_table(index='id',columns='class',aggfunc=len).ge(1).all(1)
s[s].index
#Int64Index([12291758744, 12299990440], dtype='int64', name='id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
uniques = df.groupby(['id','class']).size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(bool).all(axis=1)
uniques.loc[uniques].index.tolist()
```

or:

```
uniques = df.groupby('id')['class'].agg(set).eq(set(df['class']))
uniques.loc[uniques].index.tolist()
```

or:

```
list(set.intersection(*df.groupby('class')['id'].agg(set)))
```